# Table View layout not updating on device orientation change

Tags: swift, uitableview, screen-rotation

So I have created a tableView and have made it's frame identical to the view's frame, so therefore it should be the same size of the phone screen. However when I change the device orientation to landscape in the simulator the table view keeps the same dimensions from portrait mode.

Here is my tableView code:

```
        func setTableView() {
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.frame = view.frame
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.lightGray

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
```

Here is the viewDidLoad method:

```
       override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    setTableView()

}
```

Here is the method where I detect orientation change:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)


    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {


        print("Landscape")

    } else {



        print("Portrait")

    }
}
```

Here is what I get in the simulator. In landscape mode the table view is only half of the width of the view while it should always fill the whole screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to make sure you redraw the frame whenever the device rotates if you are using this method. Is your `viewWillTransition(to:)` method hitting `print("Landscape")` or `print("Portrait")`?

Comment: Make sure to constrain all edges of your tableView to its superView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you want the frame of a view to determine its anchors, you don't set `tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. Setting that flag to false will force it to rely on anchors as opposed to its own view frame to set its constraints.

You could try setting it to `true`, or you could try just constraining the table to the view like so:

```
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

This will constrain it to the view frame. If you do it this way, you don't need to worry about setting `tableView.frame = view.frame`. Personally, I prefer this method over relying on view's frames.